# Cannot serialize stream data asp .net core

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

Trying to deserialize objects from HTTP response.
Response stream returns information in json and I already checked if it is valid in online deserializer.
I got the object class from the API framework so I think all of the properties should be configured for the response.
Code:

```
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
                "api_url");
            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                var reponseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var data = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<Tournament>>(responseStream);
            }
            else
            {
                GetBranchesError = true;
            }
```

I see that information in responseString is correct but data objects are always null.
Weird part is that it partially works because it shows how many objects are in the responseStream but all of the object properties are nulls.
Also tried to set the stream position to 0 - didn't help.
Any idea what I am doing wrong to deserialize these objects?
Desirializer used - System.Text.Json;
Project asp .net core 3.1

Comment: I'm a little uncertain here, but I think calling `ReadAsStringAsync()` **and** reading from the stream is not possible. It's two ways of reading the same stream of data and streams are not meant for that by default.

Comment: If you move `var reponseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` one line further down, you'll probably see that `data` is no longer null and `reponseString` is now null instead

Comment: nope, still the same outcome

Comment: Yea, I see I assumed incorrectly. When you say "all of the object properties are nulls" can you show an example of what `reponseString` contains and how your `Tournament` class looks like. It sounds like the property mapping is going wrong.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/GkLV0M - not sure if you will want to go through all of them.
Last 18 entities I had to put in manually so there might be some errors there.
So if there is any mismatch none of the properties gets assigned? Shouldn't desirializer throw an Exception then?

Comment: I don't need most of the properties only 2-5 maybe. Is there a way to just parse the ones I need with Json?

Comment: I wrote an answer to your original question below. Regarding not seeing an exception: if your model (class) does not contain a matching property the deserializer will simply ignore it - that's default behaviour. And that sort of answers your last question: if you don't need all properties, just remove them from your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the properties you are looking for in the JSON array are actually wrapped inside an object called "tournament". It's easier to notice when you format the JSON string nicely like this for example:

```
[
    {
        "tournament": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "name1",
            ...
        }
    },
    {
        "tournament": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "name2",
            ...
        }
    }
]
```

To deserialize this I would suggest you make a wrapper class to handle that:

```
 public class TournamentItem
 {
    [JsonPropertyName("tournament")]
    public Tournament Tournament { get; set; }
 }
```

And then deserialize to that class:

```
var data = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<TournamentItem>>(responseStream);
```

Now `data.Tournament` will contain all the properties.

There might still be a few issues in your properties like `Spam` for example. The JSON string has a `null` as value, but the property is not nullable - I didn't check all your properties. `DeserializeAsync` will throw an error and tell you.

Comment: Thank you very much, works perfectly after I add the root class